# Multiple string bug in if else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

```
if($title=="Random 1.5"){ //value1
    $ytitle = "Custom 1.5"; 
    }
else if($title=="Another 1.6"){ //value2
    $ytitle = "Custom 1.6";
    }
else if($title=="Bold Random 1.5"){ //value3
    $ytitle = "Custom 1.7";
    }
```

Value1 and Value3 is retrieving True because (**Random 1.5**) have in string.   How to fix this problem? I wanna only post **Bold Random 1.5** value. Thank you for help.

Comment: What language is this? `php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing exact string matches, not substring matches, so unless your `$title` value was EXACTLY the same as the strings in the if() statements, there is no way that your "random 1.5" and "bold random 1.5" would ever match the same.

e.g.

```
$teststring = 'Random 1.5';

($teststring == 'Random 1.5') // evaluates to TRUE
($teststring == 'Bold Random 1.5') // evaluates to FALSE
```

but if you had

```
strpos('Random 1.5', $teststring) // integer 0 result, not boolean false
strpos('Bold Random 1.5', $teststring) // integer 4 result, not boolean false
```

would both succeed, because 'Random 1.5' shows up in both strings being searched.

As well, since you're repeatedly testing one variable against multiple values, consider using a switch() instead:

```
switch($title) {
   case 'Random 1.5':      $ytitle = 'Custom 1.5'; break;
   case 'Another 1.6':     $ytitle = 'Custom 1.6'; break;
   case 'Bold Random 1.5': $ytitle = 'Custom 1.7'; break;
}
```